# "Contact support" button

Tags: buttons, copywriting

What text alternative should I use for a contact support button? 
The motivation for this button shouldn't be to solve a problem, but to aid in the exploration of the software.  I’m thinking of  "need assistance?" or similar. The spirit should be "we're here to help". But I’m not convinced… Any ideas?

Edit:
Triggers a zendesk ticket.
It is exposed on a page that gives a step by step installation tutorial.
This button could be for users with some issue with the installation but for those who want more from the product too...
the tone should be approachable, friendly, casual.

Comment: Where is it taking people and what is it offering to the user?

Comment: And what kind of business is it?

Comment: What is the nature of your application? Who is your audience? This usually has a great impact on the tone you wish you convey (e.g. casual, authoritative, fun, formal, ...).

Comment: See this related question for some interesting thoughts about the [difference between "support" and "help"](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/13611/help-or-support).

Answer (score 1):

**It is "support" that I look for** in case of problems. If I do not see it – then I look for something else, but it is only **after** that.

Putting aside the type of business behind for a moment, I would **use something recognisable and support it with a kind message**, for example:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwlMtn.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: I don't think it is "support" in the traditional sense of being in contact with someone to help you. It's merely a tool to help users move through the application.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right path in choosing the text for your button. As you mentioned, it's not necessarily a full on "support" functionality, but rather just giving a few tips/helping a user explore the application. Being that it is lighter in nature than full on support functionality, I would move towards something you have suggested that is more casual.

The text of the button should present some meaningful information and a clear indication of what the button will help the users accomplish. It should describe what will happen when the button is clicked in the best way possible. Perhaps "**Trouble?**" or "**Problem?**" might best fit your situation here, as these terms typically convey a sense of caring and are commonly used in real world situations when someone appears to need a nudge of help.